# fsck is not running on 18.04, even with tun2fs mount count set to 1

Tags: 18.04, filesystem, fsck

fsck is not running on my root drive on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have tried `fsck.mode=force` in grub on the kernel command line to no success.

I have set the mount count to 1 with `tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sda2` and rebooted and still no fsck. Instead I just get a text message saying `you need to do a fsck on /dev/sda2`.

Any ideas on what is going on?

```
one@localhost:~$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2 
tune2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          36589912-c6ab-11e8-93a6-7085c27cfaec
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              6160384
Block count:              24641536
Reserved block count:     1232076
Free blocks:              19441110
Free inodes:              5417720
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Tue Oct  2 20:25:28 2018
Last mount time:          Tue Oct  9 22:14:49 2018
Last write time:          Tue Oct  9 22:13:35 2018
Mount count:              25
Maximum mount count:      1
Last checked:             Tue Oct  2 20:25:28 2018
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          179 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       1591485
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      5dcfe344-2b26-4b50-97e1-21952c171d2b
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0x305a8ddb
```